# How to follow up with a professor on graduate school admissions decision

Tags: graduate-admissions

I applied for graduate admission to a couple of schools and a professor from one of the schools asked me two weeks ago if I was still interested in graduate studies at his university.

I mentioned that I was still interested.

In reply, he said that he was considering me for a fellowship and that he hopes that the university administration will reply before too long.

Now, it's been two weeks and he's not gotten back to me. Should I ask him if he's received the fellowship decision yet? How should I write my email?

Answer (score 3):

A follow up email is fine. Be polite and to the point.

Comment: Should I tell him that this is a follow-up email?

Comment: Yes. Either mention it in the email or just reply to the original email

Comment: I agree, it never hurts to follow up or "check on the status of your application". Feel free to offer up anything to help the process ("Please let me know if anything else is needed on my part." ). This will pull you out of the pile one extra time and let them know that you are interested and on top of things.